# can't fetch data on tizen studio

Tags: javascript, fetch, tizen

I am developing a tizen of for tv, the problem is when I run it on the tv it can’t fetch data using even `$.ajax`, `fetch`, or `xhr`, but when I run it on the navigator or even on the tv via wits it works normally.

ps: i added the internet previlage
thank you

This is my code:

```js
const url = 'https://www.data.net/getList.php';
var macAd = null;

try {

    macAd = webapis.network.getMac();

} catch (e) {
    console.log("getMAC exception [" + e.code + "] name: " + e.name + " message: " + e.message);
}

if (null != macAd) {
    console.log("[getMAC] mac: " + mac);
}

const data = {
    mac: macAd,
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: function (result) {
        // alert('ok');
        console.log(result);
        // alert(''+result);
        var deviceList = JSON.parse(result);

        console.log(deviceList);

    } document.getElementById('loadercontainer').style.display = 'none';

    // console.log(server);

},
 
      }); document.getElementById('loadercontainer').style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: the code you posted has syntax errors, can you please review it and post the actual code used? If the problem is actually the syntax... then use an editor that highlights errors and review it

Comment: the code is runnig very good with VSCODE and WITS on the TV,
do you know how to fetch data on tizen studio , any function you know or any methods
thanks